# Push random numbers to array based on length of variable

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
let startingIndex = 2
const random = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)]
        console.log(random)

        if(startingIndex >= 2) {
            randomColor.push(random)
            console.log(randomColor)
        }
```

I'm trying to push a random word from green/yellow/red/blue into a randomColor array based off the number of the startingIndex which can be anywhere from 2-20. e.g. startingIndex = 4 so the randomColor arr should contain random words 4 times ['red','red','yellow','blue'] and changes how many items are in the randomColor arr based on what the length of the startingIndex is.
Could anyone shed some light on how this may be achieved?

Comment: _"e.g. startingIndex = 4 so the randomColor arr should contain random words 4 times"_ - Sounds like a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) wouldn't be a bad idea.

Comment: Just to clarify, does `startingIndex` represent the number of random values that you expect inside your `randomColor` array?

Comment: It is confusing that you speak of the *"length of startingIndex"*. You seem to mean the "value of startingIndex".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a loop. For instance a simple `for` loop:

```js
const colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'];
let startingIndex = 5;
const randomColors = [];

for (let i = 0; i < startingIndex; i++) {
    const random = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
    randomColors.push(random)
}

console.log(randomColors)
```

NB: it is better to use `colors.length` than hard-coded 4, as then the code will be fine when you decide to add a fifth color.

In a more functional programming style you could do:

```js
function getRandomColors(colors, length) {
    return Array.from({length}, _ =>
        colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]);
}

const randomColors = getRandomColors(['red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow'], 5)
console.log(randomColors);
```

Comment: Thank you! that was exactly what I was after!